# CryptoJS AES encryption is not symmetric?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I can't seem to get CryptoJS.AES to properly decrypt what it encrypted. Please look at this javascript code:

```
var plaintext = "Message";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, "Secret Passphrase");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
console.log(plaintext);
console.log(encrypted.toString());
console.log(decrypted.toString());
```

The resulting output is

```
Message
U2FsdGVkX18Y2Cs77gkggFx8fkEajT1uztVYRkSkt/E
4d657373616765
```

Why aren't I getting back the original `"Message"`?

Comment: Off-topic - can uplease explain why do you need encryption at client side ? if the server makes the encryption then fine but if it is the client which makes the encryption - everyone can see the value before encryption. can u explain ?

Comment: If you need, that server cannot see a message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
```

Comment: can u please answer my comment ?